# Is parsing the requirements.txt and install packages specified in requirements.txt same as pip install -r requirements.txt?

Tags: python, pip

I would like to parse the requirements.txt and pip install each package individually.

Is it the same as doing pip install -r requirements.txt? Would the behavior still be the same?

Comment: "I would like to parse the requirements.txt and pip install each package individually"—why? Please read about [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Answer (score 2):

its not the same ...

if `pip -r requirements.txt` has any failures the whole thing would quit

if you install each one individually, then presumably if one failed it would just move on

is at least one difference